# How to set name of app in itunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I am uploading an App to Apple Store.

The name of my App is "Sem Hora".

But in iTunes Connect, inside App Name,  it shows me: The following is not recommended for use in this field: hora.

Should I submit it just like this?

Thanks,

Comment: Hora is probably a registred name??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re specifying that name in an English locale, it’s probably recognizing the word “hora” as non-English. If that’s what the app’s name is meant to be, though, you’re probably fine ignoring that warning. Just make sure you set appropriate keywords in the Keywords field so people can search for your app without having to know its exact name.